# How to set fixed height with centered image in jquery LightSlidder?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a light slider with different images with different heights. If I set `isAdaptiveHeight` set to true then it will automatically adjust the height according to image but this looks not good to me.

I want to set the fixed height of the image and if any image is small then I want to set that image in the center of fixed height. This is my fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/mbjvc5u8/1/.

The first image is small and others are large so I don't want to adjust UI. I want a fixed height of lightslider with a centered image. I have tried but I am not able to do it.

Comment: img {
    display: block;
    height: 127px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}

Comment: Hi fixed height change img  - @umer

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this will work for you:

```js
$('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
  gallery: true,
  item: 1,
  loop: true,
  slideMargin: 0,
  thumbItem: 9,
  onSliderLoad: function() {


    $("img").addClass("preferredHeight");



  }


});
```

```css
.demo {
  width: 420px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.preferredHeight {
  max-height: 127px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/css/lightslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>







<div class="demo">
  <ul id="lightSlider">
    <li data-thumb="http://sc.reel-scout.com/up_images/2/2650782.jpg?10/24/2019 5:31:11 AM">
      <img src="http://sc.reel-scout.com/up_images/2/2650782.jpg?10/24/2019 5:31:11 AM" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sc.reel-scout.com/up_images/1/2650811.jpg?10/24/2019 5:31:11 AM">
      <img src="http://sc.reel-scout.com/up_images/1/2650811.jpg?10/24/2019 5:31:11 AM" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sc.reel-scout.com/up_images/5/2650815.jpg?10/24/2019 5:31:11 AM">
      <img src="http://sc.reel-scout.com/up_images/5/2650815.jpg?10/24/2019 5:31:11 AM" />
    </li>

    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-4.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-4.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-5.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-5.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-6.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-6.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-7.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-8.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-8.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-9.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-9.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-10.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-10.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-11.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-12.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-13.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-13.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this isn't the most beautiful way to solve this, but it works...